# How to read $n\frac{k}{~}$?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

So, a binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ can be read as “$n$ choose $k$”. I was wondering if there's a similar verb to describe falling factorials $n\frac{k}{~}$. I know that it's usually read as “$k$-permutations of $n$”, but I don't like this terminology for two reasons:

1. It reverses the order of arguments.
2. It doesn't use a verb.

The best terminology that I came up with is “$n$ arrange $k$”. Is there a better verb to describe this?

Comment: I dislike the notation $P(n,k)$ in the first place, preferring to use instead $n\frac{k}{~}$ as seen for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) and read it aloud as "$n$ to the $k$ falling."

Comment: Thanks. Learned something new today.

Comment: I've read this out loud as "$n$ fall $k$".

Comment: personally I like calling them truncated factorials, although an adjective not the transitive verb you're looking for - (also dislike the use of 'permutation' here reserving that for the case $(n)_n=n^\underline{n}=n!$ (leftmost my favourite notation for that, huge fan of Feller and he uses it so it stuck ;)). Not standard but suppose you could try "$n$ order $k$" or sth, just a stab in the dark, not serious suggestion but maybe the sense not far off...

Comment: I would probably say "$n$ falling $k$".